# Why isn't the content text in the underlying HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

On occasion, I see text rich pages like tabular lists that, when you go to view the source, you get almost nothing by way of HTML, and certainly not most of the content text spelled out.  Why is this?

I could have asked this way back; this is a decade old phenomenon.  A lot of times in the past it was Flash, and in Internet Explorer I used to right click and see Flash Player in the mini menu.  But more increasingly often since about 2010, there's just a larger mini-menu with no "Flash" displayed.

If I want to see what I'm reading on the page in the source code, but it's not there in the source, then how is it displayed?  I can even drag across the characters with a mouse and they highlight.  So they're encoded as text on the screen.

Just wondering what to call the technology.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools instead of "view source".

Comment: The technology is JavaScript. Your HTML becomes a DOM (Document Object Model) when it reaches the browser. JavaScript can manipulate the DOM, for example by creating new elements and adding them to the page. The DOM can be rendered back into HTML, and the developer tools that Pointy mentioned can be used to view an up to date rendering of that HTML structure.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for this.  It's become fairly evolved lately so that a lot of what a user gets when landing on a page is almost indistinguishable from past Flash.  The wait-state graphics, etc.  But "creating new elements and adding them to the page" seems to me like a lot of work for the site developer.  Maybe it's not.  Is there a standard for doing this that's spelled out in reference material somewhere?  Does that side of JavaScript have a name, this duplication of what HTML/CSS ordinarily would have been in the past on just a served HTML?

Comment: @user225626: There are several ways to add new elements to the page. There is a DOM API specification, but you'll have better luck reading tutorials and such. You may want to start here: [Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript). Some new content is created by calling methods. Some is created by using HTML within your JavaScript code, which is then rendered into new DOM elements. One can also fetch new data from a server, whether HTML or some other data structure, and use that to create the new content. This is called an XHR request, or colloquially, AJAX.

Comment: ...XHR stands for "XMLHttpRequest", which is  somewhat of a misnomer. XML is not required, nor is HTTP. And AJAX stands for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML", which also is a misnomer.